# If I have a variable in Python 2 with a string in it, how can I split this into several variables each with one character in?

Tags: python

The idea is, a user inputs an identification code, and, to check whether it meets a certain letter/number format, and that prohibited characters are not used in certain positions, each character is in its own variable.

```
number = input("What is your identification number?")
if first character is a letter:
      append to list
else:
      if first character number:
             et cetera
```

Comment: You would not do that. You would split it into a list or a dict.

Comment: can you illustrate with a code example what you are looking to do?

Comment: I have updated the question now

Answer (score 0):

First, in Python 2, `input()` does evaluation. To get a string, user should enter something in string syntax. E.g., input

```
"1234"
```

results in string "1234", but

```
1234
```

results in *number* 1234. It seems to me you need `raw_input()` instead. But you should notice Python3 doesn't evaluate, its `input` is equivalent to Python2 `raw_input`.

After this correction, you would get a string. If `number` is its variable name, `number[0]` is the very first character, `number[1]` is the second one, and so on.

I also suggest doing `strip()` on the string before analyzing it, because it's too typical for users to enter insignificant spaces before or after the real value.